# SQL - Error correlating fields with sub-query and use of UPPER

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, correlated-subquery

I am attempting to put together a query, but, I've run into an issue where SQL informs me of an error correlating when I attempt to ignore character-casing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (UPPER(a.PARTNO)),
                (SELECT WIPQTY FROM PARTMAST WHERE PARTNO = UPPER(a.partno))
FROM STOCKTRA a
WHERE SONO IN (SELECT DISTINCT(SONO) FROM SALES
               WHERE UPPER(PARTNO) LIKE "CD%" AND UPPER(COMPLETE) <>"Y")
  AND QTYISSUED < QTYREQ
```

The preceding query fails, but reducing "UPPER(a.partno)" to "a.partno" works just fine. The problem is the databases allow human entry and they do not always match in case. What can I do to continue?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(a.PARTNO), ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Always qualify *all* column references, especially when using correlated subqueries.

Comment: I added the parenthesis to see if it helped the correlation error. I am using ADO with vfpoledb. As for as qualifying all column references, I have adjusted that, but the correlation error still exists.

Comment: I suspect that VFP doesn't like having a subquery in both the field list and the Where clause.

Comment: I read elsewhere that there are limitations to when you refer to the outer query within nested queries. But, it's odd that it only fails when using "UPPER." (or lower) Would there perhaps be another way to ensure that the fields are a textual-match?